Fetching the data on two different conditions in ORACLE

I have above data in the table where I want data for RECIVER_ROLE_ID B with ACTION_STATUS=1(ACTION_STATUS contains latest UPDATED_ON Value).
My requirement is given below-

Below is the query I am trying to achieve.
SELECT
        "NOTIFICATION_DETAILS_ID",
        "RECIEVER_ROLE_ID",
        "RECIEVER_ID",
        "STATE_ID",
        "DISTRICT_ID",
        "ACTION_STATUS",
        "IS_AVAILABLE",
        "CREATED_AT",
        "UPDATED_AT",
        "CREATED_YEAR",
        "NOTIFICATION_ID",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "RECIEVER_ID" ORDER BY "UPDATED_AT" DESC) as R
    FROM
        "TRANSACTIONAL"."TBL_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS"
    WHERE
        (("RECIEVER_ID" =0)
            OR ("RECIEVER_ID" =593728771))
        AND ("RECIEVER_ROLE_ID" ='B')
        AND ("IS_AVAILABLE" =1)
        AND "STATE_ID" =24
        AND "DISTRICT_ID" =491
        AND NOTIFICATION_ID =4426


If ACTION_S column (on the screenshot) represents ACTION_STATUS you mentioned in question, then - for RECEIVER_ROLE_ID = B value of ACTION_S = 3. You said you want to get row whose ACTION_STATUS = 1 and posted such a row as desired result. I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, as there's no row whose RECEIVER_ROLE = 8 and ACTION_S = 1 in sample data.

Your desired result is just the entire row of receiver_role_id = 'B'. The only difference between this row and your result is that the column action_status is 3 in the data, but 1 in your result. If you just want to change that single value in your result, simply select hard coded 1 rather than the column action_status. If this is not what you want to do, you need to explain more detailed what logic you want.

You are correct @Jonas. ACTION_STATUS value which I require is based on the UPDATED_AT values in all 3 rows. Which one is the latest UPDATED_ON(4/16/24 12:25 PM is the latest in all three rows). That is the final ACTION_STATUS. I can not hardcode it because UPDATED_ON  can change. Hope you understand my issue.

Please edit your question and provide both sample input data and expected result as tables with text rather than as images. So people can try out possible solutions without rewriting all that text from your images. Or create a fiddle with your use case and share the url, for example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/Wh4zpMKJ


I want data for RECIVER_ROLE_ID B with ACTION_STATUS=1

Add a filter:
SELECT NOTIFICATION_DETAILS_ID,
       RECIEVER_ROLE_ID,
       RECIEVER_ID,
       STATE_ID,
       DISTRICT_ID,
       ACTION_STATUS,
       IS_AVAILABLE,
       CREATED_AT,
       UPDATED_AT,
       CREATED_YEAR,
       NOTIFICATION_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECIEVER_ID ORDER BY UPDATED_AT DESC)
         as R
FROM   TRANSACTIONAL.TBL_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS
WHERE  RECIEVER_ID      IN (0, 593728771)
AND    RECIEVER_ROLE_ID ='B'
AND    ACTION_STATUS    = 1
AND    IS_AVAILABLE     = 1
AND    STATE_ID         = 24
AND    DISTRICT_ID      = 491
AND    NOTIFICATION_ID  = 4426

For your sample data, this will return zero rows because there is no row which has both RECIEVER_ROLE_ID=B AND ACTION_STATUS=1. (If that is your desired logic then returning zero rows is the correct answer.)

If, instead, you want the lowest ACTION_STATUS where RECIEVER_ROLE_ID=B then use an inline-view:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT NOTIFICATION_DETAILS_ID,
         RECIEVER_ROLE_ID,
         RECIEVER_ID,
         STATE_ID,
         DISTRICT_ID,
         ACTION_STATUS,
         IS_AVAILABLE,
         CREATED_AT,
         UPDATED_AT,
         CREATED_YEAR,
         NOTIFICATION_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECIEVER_ID ORDER BY UPDATED_AT DESC)
           as R,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECIEVER_ID ORDER BY ACTION_STATUS)
           AS as_rn
  FROM   TRANSACTIONAL.TBL_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS
  WHERE  RECIEVER_ID      IN (0, 593728771)
  AND    RECIEVER_ROLE_ID ='B'
  AND    IS_AVAILABLE     = 1
  AND    STATE_ID         = 24
  AND    DISTRICT_ID      = 491
  AND    NOTIFICATION_ID  = 4426
)
WHERE  as_rn = 1

You appear to equate lowest ACTION_STATUS with latest UPDATED_AT and, if that is the case, you could replace the final line with WHERE r = 1.
